# How to find a document using nested value MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a Json like this:

```
     "datos_personales":
              {
              "nombre":"Dionel",
              "apellido":"Delgado",
              "fechanacimiento":"1990-12-31T04:00:00.000Z",
              "lugarNacimiento":"Venezuela, Maracaibo",
              "edad":25,
      "genero":"Masculino",
              "cedula":"21076754",
              "direccion":"San Carlos",
              "telefonofijo":"0262-6871111",
              "telefonomovil":"0262-6871111"
               },

      "datos_emergencia":
              {
              "nombre1":"Jeaynie",
              "apellido1":"Valbuena",
              "telefono1":"0262-6871111",
              "telefono2":"0262-6871111",
              "parentesco1":"Madre",
              "nombre2":"Diones",
              "apellido2":"Delgado",
              "telefono3":"0262-6871111",
              "telefono4":"0262-6871111",
              "parentesco2":"Padre"
              },

       "datos_sociales":
             {
             "civil":"Soltero",
             "estudios4":true,
             "ocupacion":"Programador Web",
             "hijos":"No"
             },
       "datos_medicotratante":
             {
             "nombre":"Naikelin",
             "apellido":"Ruiz",
             "telefono1":"0262-6871111",
             "telefono2":"0262-6871111",
             "especialidad":"Pediatría",
             "sangre":"AB",
             "rh":"Negativo",
             "seguro":"No"
              }
```

`

I need to query these kinds of documents with nodeJS using "cedula" to find them

`{"datos_personales.cedula":21076754}` << in this case

I tried using this but it doesn't fetch the document

```
var ced = 21076754;
db.getCollection('users').find({"datos_personales.cedula":ced});
```

any suggestions?

Comment: datos_personales.$.ced where $ represents cedula or the record/object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"cedula":"21076754",
```

Your result is a string (See the quotes).

Change your query to:

```
var ced = "21076754";
db.getCollection('users').find({"datos_personales.cedula":ced});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to the problem is -

find() query in MongoDB returns a cursor while findOne() query returns a JSON Object which matches the argument passed in the query. You can retrieve the desired record by using the query below -:

```
db.getCollection('users').findOne({"datos_personales.cedula":ced});
```